# How to calculate the area under a frequency polygon in R?

Tags: r, 2d, polygon, area

I am an struggeling to find a way of calculating the area under a frequency polygon like this:

```
x1 <- 1:5                         
y1 <- c(0.2, 0.14, 0.7, 0.11, 0.1) 
plot(x1, y1, type = "l", lwd = 3)   
polygon(c(1, x1, 5), c(0, y1, 0), col = "red") 
points(x1, y1,cex = 2,pch = 15)
segments(x1, 0, x1, y1)
```

so basically the area of the red zone from 1 to 5..
any suggestion would be much appreciated!!
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the bottom side of your polygons are always `0` and left and right sides are vertical, then it's nothing but summing areas of a set of trapezoids:

```
h = x1[2:5]-x1[1:4] # heights
b1 = y1[1:4] #first bases
b2 = y1[2:5] #second bases
ta = h*(b1+b2)/2 # trapezoids
pa = sum # total area
```

Of course you can generalize indices to make it work with arrays of different lengthes.